# converting obj files to a custom format in lua

Tags: lua

this code almost works at converting obj files into my custom format but when you put in a shape with more than 9 faces it gets all wiggity wack and gives me wrong numbers for the face vertexes. the format is supposed to be {vertex1,vertex2,vertex3,rvalue,gvalue,bvalue}, so say i have a face that uses vertex 1,2, and 4 then i would get {1,2,4,255,255,0}, . but if i have a face with vertex 1,2 and 10 then i get {1,2,101,255,255,0}, and i dont know why

```
-- see if the file exists
function file_exists(file)
  local f = io.open(file, "rb")
  if f then f:close() end
  return f ~= nil
end

-- get all lines from a file, returns an empty 
-- list/table if the file does not exist
function lines_from(file)
 if not file_exists(file) then return {} end
 lines = {}
 for line in io.lines(file) do 
   lines[#lines + 1] = line
 end
 return lines
end

-- tests the functions above
local file = 'cube.txt'
local lines = lines_from(file)
-- print all line numbers and their contents

for k,v in pairs(lines) do
 str = tostring(v)
 if 9 <= k then
   str = str .. ","
 end
 print("before space : "..str)
 str = str:gsub("v ", "")
 str = string.gsub(str, "v", "")
 str = str:gsub("f ", "")
 str = string.gsub(str, "f", "")
 str = str:gsub("%s+", ",")
 str = string.gsub(str, "%s+", "")
 print("before // : "..str)
 str = str:gsub("(//).(,)", ",")
 str = string.gsub(str, "//", "")
 if k >= 9 then
   print("  { " .. str .. "255,255,0 },")
 else
   print("  { " .. str .. " },")
 end
end
```

Comment: Why do you frequently switch between `str:gsub` and `string.gsub(str`?

Comment: i dont know, i just copied this off the interwebs. i really dont know much about this kind of thing

Comment: Not completely certain what this is supposed to achieve, is this really just trying to convert e.g. `'v' x y z r g b` to `{x,y,z,r,g,b}`?

Comment: well it is converting "v" x y z into {x,y,z,add some rgb values here} i just put the rgb values in so i wouldn't have to do it manually they dont really have to do with the code